# Не выбирает данные из таблицы

Tags: oracle

Создала пользователя в PL/SQL Developer через Create user и выдала ему grand-ы на select, update и т.д.

Зайдя по пользователем и пытаясь выполнить запрос

select * from patient where firstname = 'владимир'

ничего не получается. Хотя если зайти под пользователем sys и выполнить запрос, то все работает. Подскажите почему так?

```
create table Natali.phones
(
keyid number,
models VARCHAR2(100),
price number,
producer VARCHAR2(100)
)
tablespace users
pctfree 10
initrans 1
maxtrans 255
storage
(
initial 256K
next 1M
minextents 1
maxextents unlimited
);
```

Comment: А таблицу patient вы под каким пользователем создали?

Comment: под тем же natali под ним же и делаю запрос

Comment: "Зайдя по пользователем и пытаясь выполнить запрос" - ни слова о создании таблицы. Привидите, что вы выполнили.

Comment: В вопрос добавила запрос как создавала таблицу

Comment: "Хотя если зайти под пользователем sys и выполнить запрос, то все работает" - так тоже не бывает. SYS это не всевидящий, который все таблицы знает. Таблице должено предшествовать имя схемы.

Comment: А как правильно составить таблицу и выдать все права? Ну или где про это почитать?

Comment: Здесь всё работает [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d683c/1). Пока ваш вопрос непонятен.

Comment: Раз под `SYS` запрос работает, получается, что таблица `patient` находится в схеме `SYS`. Под пользователем Вы ее создать не могли, иначе бы не смогли выдать на нее гранты. Попробуйте в запросе проставить схему: `select * from sys.patient where firstname = 'владимир'`

Comment: Выполните запрос `select * from all_tables where table_name = 'PATIENT'`. В столбце `OWNER` будет название схемы, в которой создана таблица. Это чтобы окончательно убедиться, что вы создали ее там, где (не) надо.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую

Comment: @Dmitry Судя по всем комментариям, хозяйка топика "заблудилась" с таблицей. По моему, ваш комментарий наиболее подходит для исчерпыввающего ответа. И лучше под sys из dba_tables. Или оба варианта.

Comment: Обновила вопрос. Добавив новый код как я создавала таблицу. В PL/SQL Developer вошла через пользователя Natali. Заполнила таблицу, а когда делаю запрос select * from phones ps where ps.models = 'Тест1'  ничего не выводит. Пусто, хотя запись Тест1 есть

Comment: " хотя запись Тест1 есть" -  а как вы опредилили, что запись есть? Ведь запрос ничего не выводит.

Comment: Потому что запрос select * from phones отображает все данные в таблице и среди них есть эта запись. А это не может быть связано с языковыми настройками? Потому что я делаю запрос select * from phones ps where ps.keyid = 1 он работает

Comment: Я вам уже давал ссылку на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d683c/1). Поместите туда таблицу(ы), данные, запросы. Иначе  это гадание на кофейной гуще и вам вряд ли кто поможет.